# Setting an array index with strings

Tags: arrays, pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm onto creating a pair screener which need different timeframes for the value I'm looking for.

So I modified two functions I found in other screeners in TV:

The first run with chart time frame and is called with with

`array.set(s01_data, 0, request.security(s01, '', screener_bb_func(u01, s01bbl, s01bbt, s01bbw)))`

This is the function

```
screener_bb_func(flag, bbl, bbt, bbw) =>
    out_screener_bb_func = array.new_string(7, string(na))
    
    if flag 

        float bbr = 0.
        float bbBuyThUp = 0.
        float bbBuyThDown = 0.
        float bbSellThUp = 0.
        float bbSellThDown = 0.
        float trebound = 0.

        // CALCULATE BB %B
        src = close
        basis = ta.ema(src, bbl)
        dev = 2 * ta.stdev(src, bbl)
        upper = basis + dev
        lower = basis - dev
        bbr := (((src - lower)/(upper - lower))-0.5)*2

        bb_sell_th = bbt
        bb_buy_th  = bbt * -1

        // CALCULATE THRESHOLD WINDOW
        bbBuyThUp := bb_buy_th + bbw/2 
        bbBuyThDown := bb_buy_th - bbw/2
        bbSellThUp := bb_sell_th + bbw/2
        bbSellThDown := bb_sell_th - bbw/2

        if bbr[1] < bbr
             and bbr[1] < bbBuyThUp
             and bbr[1] > bbBuyThDown
            trebound := 1
        else if bbr[1] > bbr
             and bbr[1] < bbSellThUp
             and bbr[1] > bbSellThDown
            trebound := -1
        else 
            trebound := 0
                
        [trebound]
        
        array.set(out_screener_bb_func, 0, str.tostring(trebound, "#"))
   
    out_screener_bb_func
```

The second is called with a user defined timeframe

`array.set(s01_data, 1, request.security(s01, ma_tf, screener_ma_func(u01)))`

This is the function

```
screener_ma_func(flag) =>
    out_screener_ma_func = array.new_string(7, string(na))
    
    if flag 
        // Trends a
        float maFast = 0.
        float maSlow = 0.
        float maDelta = 0.
        float maDeltaChange = 0.

        maFast         := ta.ema(close, ma_fast)
        maSlow         := ta.ema(close, ma_slow)
        maDelta        := math.abs((maFast-maSlow)/maSlow)*100
        maDeltaChange  := maDelta - maDelta[ma_lookback]

        // MA TREND FUNCTION
        float trend = 0

        if maFast > maSlow 
             and ((use_ma_delta == 0) or (use_ma_delta == 1 and maDelta > ma_delta_th)) 
             and ((use_ma_d_ch == 0) or (use_ma_d_ch == 1 and maDeltaChange > ma_d_ch_th))
            trend := 1
        else if maFast < maSlow 
             and ((use_ma_delta == 0) or (use_ma_delta == 1 and maDelta > ma_delta_th)) 
             and ((use_ma_d_ch == 0) or (use_ma_d_ch == 1 and maDeltaChange > ma_d_ch_th))
            trend := -1
        else
            trend := 0
        
        [trend]
        
        array.set(out_screener_ma_func, 0, str.tostring(trend, "#"))
   
    out_screener_ma_func
```

Before to call the functions I create an array of 2  and fill it with na strings.

```
s01_data = array.new_string(2, string(na))
```

When I run the compiler I got this error, and I can't figure out how to fix it

> Cannot call 'array.set' with argument 'value'='call 'request.security' (string[])'. An argument of 'string[]' type was used but a 'series string' is expected.

I tried different ways to create the array but I can't get rid of the mismatch.